# Excluding elements with certain classes in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

The HTML I am trying to parse with Puppeteer looks something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="title"> item 1 </li>
    <li class="title hide"> item 1 </li>
</ul>
```

And I am accessing the `li` elements like this:

```
await page.$$eval("ul > li.title", nodes =>
    nodes.map(element => {
      return {
        //some attributes
      };
    })
  );
```

The outcome extended is to only retrieve elements without `class=hide`. Unfortunately `hide` is a class that's in addition to `title`, which is shared by all `<li>` elements.

How can I refactor the Puppeteer code to exclude elements with `hide` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### :not(.hide)

You should use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) CSS pseudo-class to select elements that do not include the class `.hide`:

```
await page.$$eval('ul > li.title:not(.hide)', nodes =>
  nodes.map(element => {
    return {
      // some attributes
    };
  })
);
```

#### .filter(e => !e.matches('.hide'))

On the other hand, you can also [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your `nodes` to only include the elements that are not [`matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) of the `.hide` selector string:

```
await page.$$eval('ul > li.title', nodes =>
  nodes.filter(e => !e.matches('.hide')).map(element => {
    return {
      // some attributes
    };
  })
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add `:not(.hide)` to your selector string:

```
page.$$eval("ul > li.title:not(.hide)", nodes =>
```

Comment: this is perfect.. is there a place I can learn more about what can go in the `document.querySelector()`?

Comment: `querySelector` accepts any valid CSS selector string - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) (including the links on the left of that page), they're *really* flexible